# MySQL Query for total

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables 
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have executed this query:

```
SELECT 
`tbl_players`.`id` AS `player_id`
,`tbl_players`.`player_name`
,`tbl_sports`.`sports_name`
,`tbl_scores`.`score`
FROM `tbl_players`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_scores` ON `tbl_players`.`id`=`tbl_scores`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_sports` ON `tbl_players`.`sports_id`=`tbl_sports`.`sports_id`
ORDER BY `tbl_players`.`id` ASC
```

And I got this: 
[image]

Now I want this: 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
 SELECT 
    `tbl_players`.`id` AS `player_id`
    ,`tbl_players`.`player_name`
    ,`tbl_sports`.`sports_name`
    , sum(case when tbl_scores.season=1 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season1score
   ,sum(case when tbl_scores.season=2 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season2score
,sum(case when tbl_scores.season=3 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season3score
    FROM `tbl_players`
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_scores` ON `tbl_players`.`id`=`tbl_scores`.`player_id`
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_sports` ON `tbl_players`.`sports_id`=`tbl_sports`.`sports_id`
group by `tbl_players`.`player_name`
    ,`tbl_sports`.`sports_name`,player_id
```

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation

```
select player_id,player_name,sports_name,
       sum(case when season=1 then score end) as season1_score,
       sum(case when season=2 then score end) as season2_score,
       sum(case when season=3 then score end) as season3_score
from
(
SELECT 
`tbl_players`.`id` AS `player_id`
,`tbl_players`.`player_name`
,`tbl_sports`.`sports_name`
,`tbl_scores`.`score`,`tbl_scores`.`season`
FROM `tbl_players`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_scores` ON `tbl_players`.`id`=`tbl_scores`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_sports` ON `tbl_players`.`sports_id`=`tbl_sports`.`sports_id`
)A group by player_id,player_name,sports_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

You need to PIVOT your data

```
SELECT 
 player_id,
 player_name,
 sports_name,
 sum(case when tbl_scores.season=1 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season1score,
 sum(case when tbl_scores.season=2 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season2score,
 sum(case when tbl_scores.season=3 then `tbl_scores`.`score` end) as season3score
from 
  tbl_players
left join  tbl_sports 
  on `tbl_players`.`id`=`tbl_scores`.`player_id`
left join sports 
  on `tbl_players`.`sports_id`=`tbl_sports`.`sports_id`
group by
 layer_id,
 player_name,
 sports_name,
```

Answer (score -1):

Use “distinct” selection to not get duplicates.

Just add “DISTINCT” right after “SELECT” in your query.

Example: SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;

Comment: That’s doesn’t return what it’s asked. Indeed that’s not related at all.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use inner join instead of left join